# Foreach with 2D arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to pull out value of an 2D array with foreach.
I have this array for example:

```
$ud['prc']['col1']
$ud['prc']['col2']
....
```

My loop:

```
foreach ($ud['arc'] as $name => $rank)  {
    if ($name != 'user_ID') {
        echo "<tr><td>{$name}</td><td>{$rank}</td></tr>";
    }
}
```

This code for some reason printing first a table row with the number of the array (name as '`0`' (`$ud['prc']['0']`) instead of its real name '`col1`')

Instead of printing me:

```
 <tr><td>col1</td><td>value of col1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>col2</td><td>value of col2</td></tr>
 <tr><td>col3</td><td>value of col3</td></tr>
```

It prints this:

```
 <tr><td>0</td><td>value of col1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>col1</td><td>value of col1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>1</td><td>value of col1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>col2</td><td>value of col2</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2</td><td>value of col1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>col3</td><td>value of col3</td></tr>
```

I really hope I explained myself good enough, if not comment please and tell me what you didn't understood so I could explained it to you.

I am using this in conjunction with MySQL

Here is my MySQL code:

The `$ud['arc']` array contains this:

```
$arc_q= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM arc WHERE user_ID='$id'"); 
$arc = mysql_fetch_array($arc_q); 
$ud['arc'] = $arc;
```

Comment: This array is the result of a SQL command?

Comment: Is your array filled with a kind of query results?

Comment: Show your array with values.Also change in your foreach loop `$ud['arc']` to `$ud['prc']`

Comment: @Vinicius Monteiro
Yes.
The array $ud['arc'] contain this:
$arc_q= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `arc` WHERE user_ID='$id'");
$arc = mysql_fetch_array($arc_q);
$ud['arc'] =  $arc;

Comment: worked fine for me, are you printing any table,td or tr tag above this script

Comment: Yes but only the top row. no loop with it.
@user2936213
It souposed to be 'arc'.

Comment: insert your whole array here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As its array comes from a query you have two options:

1 - Adding MYSQL_ASSOC parameter in "mysql_fetch_array" function

2 - Validate that the key is integer and skip

I personally prefer the first by not needing to create more code

Answer (score 1):

Your `$ud` array isn't an associative array, so it is indexed by numbers (0..n) and strings also, not only by strings ('prc', etc..). So your result array has double values.

If your array is generated from an SQL query, then you should use:

`$ud = mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array()`

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
$arc = mysql_fetch_array($arc_q);
```

to

```
$arc = mysql_fetch_assoc($arc_q);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! it's working perfect!
Can you please explain me what is the diffrence?

Comment: @user3209297 The function mysql_fetch_assoc, It does almost the same thing, except that it only brings the fieldname and not the indices. It is the same thing as adding the parameter MYSQL_ASSOC in mysql_fetch_array